# Get parent key Firebase Arduino

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to get the parent names of my Firebase database in Adruino. I want an array with (0123456789123, 0123456789000, etc). (see image for structure).
I only get the child names by doing:

```
FirebaseObject object = Firebase.get("/"); 
Serial.println(object.getString("0123456789123"));
```

or

```
Serial.println(Firebase.getStrung("0123456789123"));
```

How to get the database information if you don't exactly know the size or names of the parents?

Image of database structure:

[image: Image of database structure]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can determine, you need to get the JSON object out of the Firebase data with `Firebase.get("/").getJsonVariant().asObject()`. Then you can use the [methods of `JsonObject`](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonobject/) to navigate the structure.

For a complete example, see 
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/issues/288#issuecomment-338631309